# Problems compiling on an AXP server

Tags: c++, knapsack-problem

So I am trying to compile this C++ code on an AXP server and it isn't want to compile. The problem that I am trying to solve is the Knapsack problem and I am wanting to use a file to read in the data. 
Here is the code that I currently have:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    using namespace std;

    // A utility function that returns maximum of two integers
    int max(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a > b) ? a : b;
    }

    // Returns the maximum value that can be put in a knapsack of capacity W
    int knapSack(int W, int wt[], int val[], int n)
    {
        int i, w;
        int K[n + 1][W + 1];

        // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || w == 0)
                    K[i][w] = 0;
                else if (wt[i - 1] <= w)
                    K[i][w]= max(val[i - 1] + K[i - 1][w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1][w]);
                else
                    K[i][w] = K[i - 1][w];
            }
        }

        return K[n][W];
    }

    int main()
    {

        ifstream myFile;
        myFile.open("p1.txt");

        //cout << "Enter the number of items in a Knapsack:";
        int n, W;
        myFile >> n;
        int val[n], wt[n];
        //cout << "Enter the capacity of knapsack";
        myFile >> W;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            //cout << "Enter weight and value for item " << i << ":";
            myFile >> wt[i];
            myFile >> val[i];
        }

        //    int val[] = { 60, 100, 120 };
        //    int wt[] = { 10, 20, 30 };
        //    int W = 50;
        cout << "The highest valid value is: " << knapSack(W, wt, val, n) << endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

Here is the error listing that was given to me after compiling:

```
    using namespace std;
    ................^
    %CXX-E-MISNAMNAM, name must be a namespace name
    at line number 3

        int K[n + 1][W + 1];
    ..........^
    %CXX-E-EXPRNOTCONST, expression must have a constant value
    at line number 16

        int K[n + 1][W + 1];
    .................^
    %CXX-E-EXPRNOTCONST, expression must have a constant value
    at line number 16

        int val[n], wt[n];
    ............^
    %CXX-E-EXPRNOTCONST, expression must have a constant value
    at line number 45

        int val[n], wt[n];
    ...................^
    %CXX-E-EXPRNOTCONST, expression must have a constant value
    at line number 45
```

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++ although some compilers support it as an extension. The compiler hosted by the server does not support them so you'll need to change your code. Not sure why it's throwing an error on the `std` namespace though.

Answer (score 0):

### `%CXX-E-MISNAMNAM`

For historical reasons, HP C++ uses a pre-ANSI iostreams library by default on
several platforms.  This pre-ANSI iostreams library does not involve the `std`
namespace, so when you write `using namespace std;`, the compiler complains because it hasn't had any mention of `namespace std` in the headers you included.

For more details, look at section 7.1.2 in http://h71000.www7.hp.com/commercial/cplus/docs/ugv_stl.html.

If the `__USE_STD_IOSTREAM` macro is defined, HP C++ will use the ANSI
iostream library, which does live inside namespace `std`.  You can define this
macro when invoking the compiler with `/DEFINE=(__USE_STD_IOSTREAM)`.

### `%CXX-E-EXPRNOTCONST`

Variable-length arrays are a part of the C99 standard, but not part of C++.  I
am not aware that HP C++ has implemented this extension to the standard.  You
may need to rewrite your program to avoid their use (perhaps using
`std::vector` instead) to achieve compilation with HP C++.

http://h71000.www7.hp.com/commercial/cplus/docs/ugv_contents.html contains lots
of useful information concerning HP C++.